# Component disappears when removing "setup" from script in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to make a Vue 3 app. I am familiar with Vue 2 but not as much with Vue 3.

This code works:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Map :features="features" />
      <v-btn>Submit</v-btn>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>

</template>

<script setup>
  import Map from '@/components/Map.vue'
</script>
```

But when I change it to this:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Map :features="features" />
      <v-btn>Submit</v-btn>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>

</template>

<script>
  import Map from '@/components/Map.vue';
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            features: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            console.log("clicked submit")
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The "Map" component disappears completely. I guess it has something to do with removing "setup" from the script tag? But I don't have anything to set up here so I don't understand why it breaks everything. I also tried adding an empty `setup()` method under the `export default` block but that didn't help.

For reference, here is the script from the Map component:

```
  <script>
  import { ref, inject } from "vue";
  export default {
    setup() {
      const center = ref([40, 40]);
      const zoom = ref(8);
      const rotation = ref(0);
  
      return {
        center,
        zoom,
        rotation,
      };
    },
    data() {
        return {
            draw: true,
            modify: false,
        }
    },
    props: {
        features: [],
    },
    methods: {
        setToModify() {
            this.draw = false;
            this.modify = true;
        },
        clear() {
            this.draw = true;
            this.modify = false;
            this.drawnFeatures = [];
        },
    },
  };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

> `<script setup>` is a compile-time syntactic sugar for using Composition API inside Single-File Components (SFCs).

`<script setup>` improves DX a lot. For example, you don't have to register components explicitly (just import them, and use). For more features, you can read it's documentation linked above.

Now coming to your main question *"But when I change it to this: The "Map" component disappears completely."* As you would register the components in Vue 2, it's still the same in Vue 3. In your script without `setup` you must explicitly register the component like this:

```
<script>
  import Map from '@/components/Map.vue';
  export default {
    // here...
    components: {
      Map
    },
    data() {
        return {
            features: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            console.log("clicked submit")
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```